# Laravel 5.1 hosting in cpanel/CWP

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, cpanel, internal-server-error, public-html

I have tried to host a laravel 5.1 application in CentOS Web Panel (CWP) using a single account for the application. I am not trying to host multiple site in single account. I have already setup my site in

```
/home/myaccount/project/website/
```

and my structure is

```
|-home
  |-myaccount
    |-project
      |-website
        --all laravel 5.1 directories
    |-public_html
```

I have tried using these solutions:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/where-do-you-set-public-directory-laravel-5
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/laravel-51-on-shared-hosting-not-working?page=3
but i am still getting this 500 error

[image: 500 Internal Server Error]
Can i get any solutions for the problem. I have configured most of the parts but i still think there is some missing configurations.
I have all requirements for Laravel 5.1 to support.

Edit:
Looked into the error_log located in :

```
/usr/local/apache/logs/error_log
```

and found the error to be as

```
SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File ".. /public_html/index.php" is writeable by group.
```

Comment: Check PHP logs. Did you run `composer install` ?

Comment: @balping Did `~/bin/composer install` , `~/bin/composer update` also deleted and recloned the whole project many times but i always get this error when i try to `symlink` for 5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it myself checking the error_log located in

```
/usr/local/apache/logs/error_log
```

Solution:

1. Edit the `~/.bash_profile`
2. Add this   `umask 022`  to bash_profile
3. To Sort already existing file `chmod -R 755 {file_path}`

Viola the problem goes away.